# MC Music gone crazy!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I play minecraft in singular player my music goes crazy: for instance 1 song would start playing, but after a while another song starts at the SAME TIME! It very annoying. when I turn my music to off in the music & sound area it doesn't turn off! So I end up having to turn off my master volume.

I cant stand the silence.
 plz help me

Comment: If you click on the volume icon in your system tray, there will be a button at the bottom for "mixer". If you click that, it will show all of your running programs. What happens if you mute Minecraft on that panel?

Comment: Maybe you're referring to some of the ambient sounds that are very similar to 'music' in minecraft?

Comment: where do I find the "system tray"?

Comment: @diana the bottom right.

Comment: @diana the system tray is the collection of small icons on the lower right of your screen. it has the clock, the sound picture, your network picture and likely some others. if you rightclick the sound picture you can open your 'mixer'

Comment: But when I go to the volume mixer I do not find Minecraft's sound all I see is: Speakers, Window's Sound's, Adobe Flash Player, and Mozilla Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are playing in minecraft 1.7.2, there is a bug where multiple songs can load at once, this was fixed in 1.7.3/1.7.4 update.

Comment: Can you link to the relevant patch notes?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is even in the patch notes, all I know is that I encountered this frustrating bug every time I played minecraft and it really pissed me off. I would recommend updating to minecraft 1.7.5 I have yet to encounter this bug in the new bug fix update.

Comment: Don't be pissed since it isn't in the patch notes, I went through about 50 pages of posts on the official mojang website and it wasn't in any of the patch notes.

Comment: Btw, if you ever want the music off, just turn it down to 2% or something like that. Fully turning it off doesn't work.